# How to work with SimpleXMLElement->addAttribute namespaces?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I'm just tring to generate next xml code by SimpleXMLElement() using :

```
<WebOrders xmlns="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

But code like that

```
$webOrders = new SimpleXMLElement('<WebOrders/>');
$webOrders->addAttribute('xmlns', 'http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/');
$webOrders->addAttribute('xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
$webOrders->addAttribute('xmlns:xsd', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
```

makes

```
<WebOrders xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/"><WebOrder/><WebOrder/></WebOrders>
```

only.